# Multiple connections webserver C

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, webserver, winsock

I need to write a very basic webserver in C. Below is my code.

The problem is that I cannot manage multiple connections correctly because when I open new tabs on my browser I always get the message "Connection #1", instead of "Connection #2", "Connection #3"...

Where is the error?  Thanks

Here is my code https://codeshare.io/a393M4
or here:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <WinSock2.h>
#define socket_t SOCKET
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define WSACleanup()
#define INVALID_SOCKET (~0)
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define closesocket close
#define ioctlsocket ioctl
#define socket_t int
#endif
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>



void print_time(char *buf, size_t buf_len) {
    time_t rawtime;
    time(&rawtime);
    struct tm info;
#ifdef _WIN32
    gmtime_s(&info, &rawtime);
#else
    gmtime_r(&rawtime, &info);
#endif

    const char *days[] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    const char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    snprintf(buf, buf_len, "%s, %i %s %i %02i:%02i:%02i GMT", days[info.tm_wday], info.tm_mday, months[info.tm_mon], 1900 + info.tm_year,
            info.tm_hour, info.tm_min, info.tm_sec);
}


typedef struct sock_list {
    socket_t s;
    struct sock_list *next;
} sock_list;


void sock_list_insert(sock_list **list, socket_t s) {
    sock_list *i = *list;
    sock_list *j = *list;
    sock_list *n = malloc(sizeof(sock_list));

    n->s = s;
    n->next = 0;

    while (i) {
        j = i;
        i = i->next;
    }

    if (j) {
        j->next = n;
    }
    else {
        *list = n;
    }
}


int sock_list_len(sock_list *list) {
    int c = 0;
    sock_list *i = list;
    while (i) {
        ++c;
        i = i->next;
    }
    return c;
}


int main() {
    int port = 80;

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
#endif

    socket_t sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Cannot open socket (-2)\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return -2;
    }
    unsigned long mode = 1;
    ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &mode);  // set as non-blocking


    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);


    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Cannot bind socket (-3)\n");
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -3;
    }


    listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);
    sock_list *conn_list = 0;


    for (;;) {

        sock_list *i = conn_list;
        fd_set set;
        FD_ZERO(&set);
        while (i) {
            FD_SET(i->s, &set);
            i = i->next;
        }
        select(0, &set, &set, &set, 0);


        struct sockaddr_in client;
        memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
        int c = sizeof(client);
        socket_t ns = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &c);
        if (ns != INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("new sock %u\n", ns);
            sock_list_insert(&conn_list, ns);
        }


        int count = 0;
        i = conn_list;
        while (i) {
            ++count;
            int recv_sz;
            char msg[4096];
            char tbuf[512];

            print_time(tbuf, 512);

            recv_sz = recv(i->s, msg, 4096, 0);

            if (recv_sz > 0) {
                char html[4096];

                snprintf(html, 4096, "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Ciao</title>"
                                     "<style type='text/css'>body {margin: 200px auto;text-align: center;color: #393939;}</style>"
                                     "</head><body><h1>Connection %i</h1><h1>%s</h1></body></html>", count, tbuf);
                snprintf(msg, 4096, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %i\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n%s",
                         strlen(html),
                         html);

                send(i->s, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
                printf("send to %u\n", i->s);

            }
            i = i->next;
        }

        fflush(stdout);
#ifdef _WIN32
        Sleep(1);
#else
        usleep(1000);
#endif
    }


    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I need to write a very basic webserver in C.", this is clearly not the purpose of C, you should change to  python or similar. C is for "complete http server" not "very basic" because you will need a lot of code just for a "basic server" and your server will be terrible.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, but use some library as for example this: https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/

Comment: This is CLEARLY not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code is likely to get stuck in recv(), as your accepted sockets are blocking. Also you have not put listening socket(which you have made non-blocking) in any of select() FDSETs

Comment: The 1st thing to do when (not just) doing debugging is to implement (complete) error handling!

Comment: @Ctx licensing issues unfortunately

Comment: @Pras I never get stuck. I added what you suggested but still not working properly. To clarify, the webserver works fine, but from the server side I only see a single connection

Comment: @user1738687 the mentioned library uses the LGPL, so it should be no problem to use it in an otherwise proprietary product.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `listen()` can fail, so need to be checking the returned value to assure the operation was successful, otherwise, cleanup and exit program

Comment: regarding: `select(0, &set, &set, &set, 0);`  the first parameter cannot be 0,  it must be the max socket value +1.  the third and forth parameters should be NULL as the code is not checking write availability nor I/O excetions.

Comment: regarding: `socket_t ns = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &c);` the third parameter should be of type `socklen_t`, not `int`

Comment: regarding: `send(i->s, msg, strlen(msg), 0);`  the code should be checking the returned value to assure the operation was successful, including checking to assure that all the bytes have been written.

Comment: this statement: `int port = 80;`  should be: `uint16_t port = 80;`  where `uint16_t` is defined in the header file: ctype.h

Comment: the function: `recv()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: regarding the string: `"Content-Length: %i\r\n" which part of the parameters to `snprinf()`,  the format specifier `%i` is not correct of the `size_t` returned from the call to` strlen()`  suggest: `%lu` (there is also a preferred format specifier, as defined in the header file: inttypes.h)

Comment: in general, each new connection should be passed to a thread (as an entry in a 'thread pool') and let that thread handle all future communication with that client.

Answer (score 0):

the 'count' is always 1 because of the following code:

```
    int count = 0;
    i = conn_list;

    while (i)
    {
        ++count;
```

suggest moving the initialization of 'count' to before:

```
for (;;)
```

Then why rewrite all the HTML pages every time for every new connection?

I would think only need to write a specific HTML page once when a new connection is found